# C++ higher order functions

Tags: c++, function, higher-order-functions

I a started learning some C++ and don't understand how higher order functions work in C++. Can someone explain c++ 11 functions of higher order on a simple example? I can't find much information on this topic anywhere online.

Comment: "Higher order"? In what context, like polynomials? Can you give an example?

Comment: Higher order functions are simply functions that take functions as parameter or return a function. In C++ that's any callable object (`std::function`, function pointer, lambda, functor, anything that implements `operator()`)

Comment: 5th Google result http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/170464/c11-support-for-higher-order-list-functions

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Many of the standard C++ functions in the [`<algorithm>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) header are examples of higher-order functions.

For example the `count_if` function takes a unary predicate which is a type of callable function and returns a count of objects that match the given predicate. Since `count_if` is a function which takes another function as an argument, this makes it a [higher-order function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function).

This example doesn't make use of any C++11 features, but C++11 just augments the existing support for higher-order functions in previous C++ standards:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

bool is_even(int i) {
  return i % 2 == 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  std::vector<int> v;
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    v.push_back(i);
  }
  std::cout
    << "count = "
    << std::count_if(v.begin(), v.end(), &is_even)
    << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Converting this into an example that uses some C++11 features is fairly trivial:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  std::vector<int> v = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

  std::cout
    << "count = "
    << std::count_if(v.begin(),
                     v.end(),
                     [](int i) -> bool { return i % 2 == 0; })
    << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

In the second example, I changed the vector initialization to use [list initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization), and I've replaced `is_even` with a [lambda expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda).

Comment: in your example, you switched callable function `iseven()` definition to `[](int i) -> bool { return i % 2 == 0; }`, what's the use of [] here (c++11 standard)?

Comment: It begins a lambda expression.